# Displaying Specific Events in Specific Month?

Tags: android, listview, calendar

I am using CalenderView to Display the Date and Below CalenderView I have Used ListView to Display the date(day) with Events.I am able to parse all the Events with Day but what i want is that **Display Specific Day and Events under Specific Month**.How can this be achieved?

**CalenderFragment**

```
public class CalenderFragment extends Fragment {
    CalendarView calendar;
    String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/getEvents";
    String access_token;
    ListView listView;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calender, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        calendar = (CalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view,
                                            int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.calenderlist);
        SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(getContext());
        session.checkLogin();
        access_token = session.getAccesstToken();

        makeJsonObjectRequest();

        return view;
    }

    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL = Navigation_URL;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            ArrayList<CalenderPojoStudent> student_list_calender = new ArrayList<>();

                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String StartAt =  jsonObject.getString("StartAt").substring(6,10);
                                String Title =  jsonObject.getString("Title");
                                student_list_calender.add(new CalenderPojoStudent(StartAt, Title));
                            }
                            CalenderAdapter calenderAdapter = new CalenderAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_calender);
                            listView.setAdapter(calenderAdapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }
/*
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("id", master_id);
                map.put("accessID", accessID);
                map.put("currentUser", master_id);
                return map;

            } */
        };


        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // do s.th.
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

**CalenderAdapter**

```
public class CalenderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    Context mContext;

    ArrayList<CalenderPojoStudent> student_class_calender = null;
    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";

    public CalenderAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<CalenderPojoStudent> student_class_calender) {

        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.student_class_calender = student_class_calender;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //   System.out.println(student_class_calender.size());
        return student_class_calender.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return student_class_calender.get(position);
        // return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // final ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder viewHolder;
        final Holder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calender_student_listitems, parent, false);

            // well set up the ViewHolder
            //  viewHolder = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder();
            viewHolder = new Holder();
            viewHolder.student_calender_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_calender_date);
            viewHolder.student_calender_events = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_calender_events);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        } else {
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            //  viewHolder = (ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder) convertView.getTag();
            viewHolder = (CalenderAdapter.Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // Log.d(TAG, "@@ postion:" + postion + " getTeacherName" + student_class_schedule.get(postion).getTeacherName());
        viewHolder.student_calender_date.setText(student_class_calender.get(postion).getDate());
        viewHolder.student_calender_events.setText(student_class_calender.get(postion).getEvents());


        // convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        return convertView;
    }

    class Holder {


        TextView student_calender_date;
        TextView student_calender_events;


    }

}
```

**CalenderPojoStudent**

```
public class CalenderPojoStudent {
    String Date;
    String Events;

    public CalenderPojoStudent(String date, String events) {
        Date = date;
        Events = events;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public String getEvents() {
        return Events;
    }

    public void setEvents(String events) {
        Events = events;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;

    }
}
```

**calender_student_listitems**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#DAE2E6"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_calender_date"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:text="04"
        android:textColor="#008b8b"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_calender_events"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="Sports Day"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**calender**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2E353D"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/calander" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="Calendar"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/calenderlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "EventID": 2,
    "Title": "Event1",
    "Description": "gdfg",
    "StartAt": "2017-03-01T00:00:00",
    "EndAt": "2017-03-02T05:45:00",
    "IsFullDay": true,
    "IsHoliday": false
  },
  {
    "EventID": 4,
    "Title": "f",
    "Description": "sdf",
    "StartAt": "2017-03-02T09:52:00",
    "EndAt": "2017-03-02T10:52:00",
    "IsFullDay": false,
    "IsHoliday": false
  },
  {
    "EventID": 3,
    "Title": "Event3",
    "Description": "dsf",
    "StartAt": "2017-03-03T00:00:00",
    "EndAt": "2017-03-04T05:45:00",
    "IsFullDay": true,
    "IsHoliday": true
  },
  {
    "EventID": 10,
    "Title": "xcgz",
    "Description": "zxcv",
    "StartAt": "2017-04-02T00:00:00",
    "EndAt": "2017-04-03T00:00:00",
    "IsFullDay": true,
    "IsHoliday": false
  },
  {
    "EventID": 9,
    "Title": "xzcvzx",
    "Description": "vxzvc",
    "StartAt": "2017-04-04T00:00:00",
    "EndAt": "2017-04-05T00:00:00",
    "IsFullDay": true,
    "IsHoliday": false
  },
  {
    "EventID": 14,
    "Title": "afagag",
    "Description": "",
    "StartAt": "2017-04-04T00:00:00",
    "EndAt": "2017-04-05T00:00:00",
    "IsFullDay": true,
    "IsHoliday": true
  }
]
```

How do display the events of specific month on the listView on the basais of Calender Month?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library it has som e for showing events in calendar.DOts will be shown under the dates. [MaterialCalendarView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)
Search for decorator you can use wth dates in that library.

```
materialCalendarView.setDateTextAppearance()
materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new OpenSansDecorator(getActivity()));  
      materialCalendarView.setHeaderTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_ProfileCalenderHeader);
```

This can be used to show dots in calendar and u can implement a logic to show recylerview based on date click in calendar.

Refer [this](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/DECORATORS.md) for events decoration in the lib  :

Comment: Cannot i assign the january as 1,Feb as 2 and Compare my Date and Display Within the ListView?

Comment: u can get the month from caendar i think so

Comment: Can you please provide some logic.That How can i populate ListView under Specific month then?